# IdentityUserClaim: When to add one?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In Asp.Net Identity there is class called `IdentityUserclaim`. When should I assign one to user? What are the advantages of assigning **IdentityUserClaim** to a user?

Answer (score 0):

Its just an easy way for you to store arbitrary claims in the user db that will automatically get added to the User.Identity ClaimsPrincipal that is generated for the user when they sign in.

Comment: I believe that this is also how the new AspNET.Identity provider handles roles (via ClaimTypes.Role)